# RSync hanging for hours when using files-from option

Tags: freeze, rsync, data-transfer

I'm running into a persistent problem with rsync when using the file-from option. This option lets me pass rsync a pregenerated list of files I want to transfer. Currently I'm using the following

```
rsync -a -s -H --logfile=./rsync-logfile_1460 --files-from=./f.1460 /source/path /dest/path
```

So the file list is in the file f.1460. This file list corresponds to around 250k files from a single directory that has 500k files in it (I know, it's insane but that's how this genomics application spits out its results). The process moves along pretty well until it has transferred around 100k files and then it hangs for around 7 hours. Then it starts up again, moves another 10k to 20k and hangs for another 7 hours. Rinse. Lather. Repeat. This is a problem as we are moving a large amount of data (100s of TB) from one data storage system to another.

There is more than enough space on the target file system and the source file system doesn't have any faults. Note, both file systems are lustre running over ZFS. The rsync is running on a node with 128 cores and 256GB of RAM so I'm not resource limited.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with rsync? Are there better options I can use to get around this? I'm not seeing errors in the rsync log when it hangs - it sits there for ~7 hours not doing much of anything.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This answer might help: https://serverfault.com/a/207693/234750

Comment: I'll give that a try but the directory doesn't actually have any hard links in it. Of course, that doesn't mean the hard links option isn't messing things up.

Comment: Technically, your directory contains around 250k hard links.

Comment: Ha. True enough. I'll be starting the test in a few minutes so I'll let people know if it works. Either way thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I got rid of the -H option and it froze up again. I got around 112k files in before it froze. So I guess that's not the easy fix I was hoping for :)